# Ruby: undefined method `length' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with this fragment of code, because for some reason I can´t use the method `length`:

```
def comidayprop()
  aux=""
  tam=@comida.lenght
  i=0
  for i in (0..tam-1)
    aux<<"- #{@comida[i]}#{@prop_aprox[i]}#{@prop_exact[i]}"
    i+=1
    aux+="\n"
  end
  "#{aux}"
end
```

Later, I use this to show the content saved in `aux`:

```
def to_s
  "Menú basado en #{@tipo}:\n#{m_nombre}\n#{comidayprop}\n#{vct}\n"
end
```

I tried to use `count` and `size` instead of `length`, but they don't work.

Comment: Two things, try to indent your code, you have a preview to check this before posting. The other, do you know where you define `@comida`? you are trying to use the length method of `@comida`, and `@comida` is undefined

Comment: Try posting more complete code, for example the full file of these methods that you posted, that would be really helpful

Comment: There's no reason to use `"#{aux}"`, just put `aux`. Also try and use the `aux << "\n"` type pattern instead of `+=`.

Comment: I'd recommend reading through a Ruby style guide, and follow its recommendations. It'll help you write code that's idiomatic and would be more acceptable in a team-environment or if you ever shared your code or someone else had to maintain it. As a starting point, use whitespace around your operators.

Answer (score 2):

First, you wrote `lenght` instead of `length`.

Then, the object you're calling `length` on is nil, which could mean it was not properly initialized or there is some missing data.

Also, you don't need to increment `i` with `i = i+1`, this is done by the `for` loop. By the way, using `each` is considered a better practice than `for`.

Finally, `"#{aux}"` is just `aux` when `aux` is already a string.

You won't be able to call `size`, `count` or anything interesting on `@comida` as long as it is nil.

Your code could be a bit shorter.

This one will return an empty string when `@comida` is nil. But should it be possible for `@comida` to be nil?:

```
def comidayprop
  aux=""
  (@comida || []).each_with_index do |x,i|
    aux<<"- #{x}#{@prop_aprox[i]}#{@prop_exact[i]}\n"
  end
  aux
end
```

Comment: You´re right '@comida' is nil like '@prop_aprox' and '@prop_exact'. I solve the problem, and now it works perfectly, many thanks